# Build a website with login and user profile with Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, user-profile

Which tools should I use to build a website on which users can create an account which is linked to a profile if I use a bootstrap frontend ? Are their solutions easy to put in place ?

Comment: Bootstrap will only help you with building the UI of your application. What are you trying to build, more specifically? You'll most likely need a back-end for your application, or a service that handles authorization.

Comment: I need users to be able to create an account, login, and have a user profile. Are there tools compatible with bootstrap to do this ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by bamboo_inside, Twitter Bootstrap is used for the frontend UI.  There are definitely solutions out there.  You should be able to implement most log in and profile solutions with a bit of knowledge in server-side languages such as PHP.

- You could build your own with PHP and MYSQL.
- You could integrate something like the Oauth 2.0 solution from
  Google. (others such as Facebook or Twitter's sign in solutions).

Pretty much every solution will require you to do some server side programming.

Check out [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) for more info on the Google solution